# $wpdb->insert() throws "foreign key constraint fails" error

Tags: php, wordpress, foreign-keys

I have the following code:

```
$chck = $wpdb->insert( 'poruke_viber', array(
                                       'id' => $data['message_token'],
                                        'tekst' => $messageText, 
                                        'primljena' => '1',
                                        'user_id' => $user['id'],
                                        'vrijeme_epoch' => $data['timestamp']
                        ));
logData($wpdb->last_error);
```

and it throws error:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

It bugged me for couple of hours, I checked that I already have user_id in my parent table, and everything.

Until I tried replacing `insert` with `query`.

So when I did:

```
$wpdb->query('INSERT INTO poruke_viber (id, tekst, primljena, user_id, vrijeme_epoch)
        VALUES ("'.$data['message_token'].'","'.$messageText.'","1","'.$user['id'].'","'.$data['timestamp'].'")');
```

**It worked like a charm!**

I'm here with the working code but not understanding what happened.
Is it wrong to use `$wpdb->insert()` on a table that has a foreign key?

Comment: I think what is happening, is in your `->insert` the values are being set as strings and your database engine may be setup not understand that `"1"` == `1`. You could try passing the `$format` array to specify the data types.

Comment: For data types and more information on that `$format` array, check the documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/